# Как получить ассоциативный массив указанных колонок?

Tags: postgresql

Хочу выбрать некоторый колонки из таблицы в виде ассоциативного массива (или объекта, если угодно). Например есть колонки в таблице `type, alias, is_active`. Хочу на выходе в каждой строчке получить данные такого типа:

```
{
    "type": "simple",
    "alias": "dom",
    "is_active": true    
}
```

- Можно воспользоваться функцией `row_to_json`. Но при её использовании: `row_to_json(row("type", "alias", "is_active"))`  на выходе получим: `{"f1":'simple', "f2":"dom", "f3":true}`. Имена в виде f1,f2,f3 меня не устраивают
- Можно воспользоваться функцией `json_build_object`. Но при таком подходе нужно имя ключа всегда задавать вручную: `json_build_object('type', type, 'alias', alias, 'is_active', is_active)` - что тоже неудобно, если полей будет много или нужен вложенный объект ассоциативный и т.д.

Как можно выбрать ассоциативный массив без лишних манипуляций? Есть ли способ написать просто  что-то типа `SELECT json_assoc(type, alias, is_active) FROM table` и получить неообходимый результат?

*Postgres* v9.6

Answer (score 0):

> Но при её использовании: row_to_json(row("type", "alias", "is_active"))

А синтаксис `row` то вам зачем?

```
select row_to_json(tablename) from tablename;
```

Если хотите все поля таблицы. Или можете сформировать те поля, какие нужны, например, подзапросом:

```
select row_to_json(s) from (
    select type, alias, is_active from tablename
) as s;
```

Comment: `А синтаксис row то вам зачем?` - кроме упоминания её тут https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/functions-json.html я не нашел инфы, поэтому подумал, что она возвращает данные из указанных колонок в виде выборки строки row (типа как подзапрос, с лимитом 1). "row_to_json(tablename)" - возвращает всё, а нужно только некоторые колонки. `те поля, какие нужны, например, подзапросом:` - то есть без подзапроса никак? Просто функцией, как примерно я написал в вопросе? Жаль